# Changing Customer Fields Quickbooks SDK - QBFC13

Tags: c#, sdk, quickbooks

I am working on a C# program that reads and writes to QB using the QB SDK (QBFC13).
I have been able to modify the information about a customer with the code below.

```
  IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 13, 0);
  requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

  ICustomerQuery CustomerQueryRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerQueryRq();
  CustomerQueryRq.ORCustomerListQuery.ListIDList.Add(customerid);
  IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);
  string editSequence = Xmlhelper.getField(responseMsgSet, "EditSequence");

  ICustomerMod customerModRq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomerModRq();
  customerModRq.ListID.SetValue(customerid);
  customerModRq.EditSequence.SetValue(editSequence);
  customerModRq.Email.SetValue(value);
  customerModRq.Cc.SetValue(value);
  customerModRq.Phone.SetValue(value);
  customerModRq.AltPhone.SetValue(value);
  customerModRq.Mobile.SetValue(value);
  customerModRq.Fax.SetValue(value);
```

This works fine, however in our quickbooks we have other items within the customer like website, facebook, twitter. etc that I don't know how to access and change them.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some fields that were added to the new version of QuickBooks that have not been implemented in the SDK yet. These fields, like Website, Twitter, LinkedIn etc. can not be accessed until Intuit updates the SDK.

As a workaround, you could create Custom Fields in QuickBooks that mimic these built in fields. Custom fields can be accessed using DataExt of the SDK. There's detailed information in the Programmer's Guide on how to create, query, and modify these fields.

Comment: Thank you hpjchobbes. I noticed tho, that the field webiste is available but doesn't post the update. Any idea why that happens?